# How to generate key store from certificates?

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, keytool

I am trying to create a keystore which has extension of jks from exsiting certificate file.
Using the  (CERT) certificate file I have, How can I create key-store (JKS) using Java key-tool?

Comment: I think the manual covers what you are trying to do: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To generate keystores:

```
keytool -genkey -alias server -keyalg RSA -keystore server.jks
keytool -genkey -alias client -keyalg RSA -keystore client.jks
```

Getting server's self signed public key certificate and storing it in client's keystore and getting and storing client's self signed public key certificate in server's keystore:

```
keytool -export -file server.cert -keystore server.jks -storepass 123456 -alias server
keytool -export -file client.cert -keystore client.jks -storepass 123456 -alias client
```

Import certificate files in the JKS files:

```
keytool -import -file client.cert -keystore server.jks -storepass 123456 -alias client
keytool -import -file server.cert -keystore client.jks -storepass 123456 -alias server
```